# SQL Server : join results in too many rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have two SQL Server tables.

The first table is called `Content` and contains -- among other things -- columns called

```
FileID, FileHighResolutionID, FileHighResolutionProID, FileVectorID
```

The second table is called `Analytics` and contains -- among other things -- a column called `FileID`. This column contains the value from one of the four aforementioned columns in `Content`.

Executing the following...

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Analytics a
WHERE 
    a.Created BETWEEN '2017-03-07' AND '2017-03-08'
```

results in 782 rows.

But executing the following...

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Analytics a
INNER JOIN 
    Content c ON (c.FileID = a.FileID OR c.FileHighResolutionID = a.FileID OR c.FileHighResolutionProID = a.FileID OR c.FileVectorID = a.FileID)
WHERE 
    a.Created BETWEEN '2017-03-07' AND '2017-03-08'
```

results in 843 rows.

I know I have something wrong with my JOIN, because now I have 61 too many records. I have tried INNER JOINs, LEFT OUTER JOINS, RIGHT OUTER JOINs, but each results in 61 mysterious extra records.

Can some SQL expert please review and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I am no expert but isn't it a bad practice to select * from tables?

Comment: I suspect you have multiple rows in Content that tie to a single Analytics row.

Comment: @EvanCarslake it's for brevity.   I really didn't think spelling out 32 columns in each of my examples would add much for posterity.  :-)

Comment: @flaZer gah, rookie move.   This is a dev system.  I apparently had cut and pasted some data early on, and forgot to remove it.

Comment: What flazer said, there must be rows in one table that have multiple matches in the other. Try grouping by the key fields using `having count (*) > 1` to find the dupes in either table.

Answer (score 2):

You must have figured out by now that the issue is that the `OR` is matching multiple columns in `c`.  You get a separate row for each match.  Voila!  Unexpected rows.

One method to resolve this uses a "lateral join".  This is like a correlated subquery, but it can return more than one column and more than one row (not needed here).  In SQL Server, this is implemented using `APPLY`:

```
SELECT a.*, c.*
FROM Analytics a CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 c.*
      FROM Content c 
      WHERE a.FileID IN (c.FileId, c.FileHighResolutionID, c.FileHighResolutionProID, c.FileVectorID)
    ) c
WHERE a.Created BETWEEN '2017-03-07' AND '2017-03-08';
```

This returns an arbitrary matching row.  You can get a specific row with an `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT a.*, c.*
FROM Analytics a CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 c.*
      FROM Content c 
      WHERE a.FileID IN (c.FileId, c.FileHighResolutionID, c.FileHighResolutionProID, c.FileVectorID)
      ORDER BY (CASE a.FileId WHEN c.FileId THEN 1 c.FileHighResolutionID THEN 2 c.FileHighResolutionProID THEN 3 c.FileVectorID THEN 4
                END)
    ) c
WHERE a.Created BETWEEN '2017-03-07' AND '2017-03-08';
```

Note:  I do agree with the answer that questions the use of `BETWEEN` with date/time values.  This is dangerous, because times cause misleading logic.  I strongly recommend one of the following:

```
WHERE a.Created = '2017-03-07'
WHERE a.Created >= '2017-03-07' AND a.Created < '2017-03-09';
```

Comment: It ended up being some dirty dev data that was causing the problem, but this is very good information to have.    Can you clarify what is "dangerous" about BETWEEN.   I understand BETWEEN is all inclusive, but the only issue I can see is if the record was created at the exact millisecond of 12:00am which is super unlikely.

Comment: @eat-sleep-code I'd advice going through this: https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/b/weblog/archive/2016/01/28/don-39-t-use-between-with-datetime

Comment: Aaron Bertrand explains this well:  https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need data from `Content` table, you could go for `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Analytics AS A
WHERE A.Created >= '2017-03-07'
    AND A.Created < '2017-03-08'
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM Content AS C
        WHERE A.FileID IN (C.FileID, C.FileHighResolutionID, C.FileHighResolutionProID, C.FileVectorID)
        );
```

`EXISTS` will yield either `true`/`false` in `WHERE` condition and will not create dupes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I needed the data from Content.

Comment: Then solution, provided by Gordon Linoff should do the trick just fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another bad practice is using BETWEEN in a WHERE clause when filtering on dates

```
WHERE a.Created >= '20170307' AND a.Created < '20170308'
```

You have more rows in the second query because you are joining on multiple columns and this might be the reason why you are getting more records. In your first query you aren't joining with another table.